# TObjectList<T>.Count causes Invalid pointer operation

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2009

In Delphi 2009, I had no major problems with Generics so far (using Generics.Collections lists, with no special Generics features).

Now I found this code will cause a 'Invalid pointer operation' in the line which accesses `MyList.Count`. (MyList.Contains and MyList.IndexOf cause the same error).

The error disappears if I declare TMyList = `class(TList<TMyEntry>)`;

Should I avoid `TObjectList<T>` or is something else in my code causing this error?

```
type
  TMyEntry = class(TStringlist);
  TMyList = class(TObjectList<TMyEntry>);

procedure TListTests.TestAV;
var
  Entry: TMyEntry;
  MyList: TMyList;
begin
  MyList := TMyList.Create;
  try
    Entry := TMyEntry.Create;
    try
      MyList.Add(Entry);
      Assert(MyList.Count = 1);  // <--- fails
    finally
      Entry.Free;
    end;
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It's Delphi 2009 that you should avoid. Huge numbers of generics bugs in that version.

Comment: It's probably a D2009 bug. Your example works in Delphi XE2, with the exception that you should not free Entry after adding because the default behavior of TObjectList is to own the objects.

Comment: Come to think of it, that may be the problem. It is not the assertion that fails, but the line with "MyList.Free" right? Remove the line with Entry.Free (or pass False as a parameter to the list constructor) and it should work.

Comment: Have you looked at this example: [Generics Collections TObjectList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectList_%28Delphi%29)?

Comment: Many thanks for the comments! I found that the problem was the missing Free. The original problem in my code did not use Count but Contains and I posted a bad example, sorry. I have opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940082/tobjectlistt-contains-causes-access-violation

Comment: But as David said, it's better to avoid using generics in D2009 (from my own experience), most of the bugs found should be fixed by Update 3, so if you still want to go this way, Update 3 is a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TObjectList` named *Object* List because it owns objects wich it stores. so you have not to free objects wich list contains yourself.  `TObjectList` does it for you.
I've tested you example code in Delphi2010. And I get AV  in `MyList.free()`  line. the reason is that you do `Entry.Free`. List doesn't  know about this, and tries to `free` object again. 
`TObjectList`s constructor has boolean parametrer `ownsObjects` (default = true), you can use it and free objects, wich it contains manually.

Comment: Actually, "object list" does not imply ownership (at least for me). Ant the fact that you can have an object list that does not own its objects contradicts your first sentence.

Comment: Well the converse is that TList<T lacks the fundamental ability that TObjectList<T> was created to introduce. And thus, there is a general correlation, especially since the ownsObjects param defaults to true.  So unless you defeat it explicitly, it implies ownership.