# TObjectList<T>.Contains causes Access Violation in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2009

In Delphi 2009, I had no major problems with Generics so far (using Generics.Collections lists, with no special Generics features).

Now I found this code will cause an AV in the line which accesses `MyList.Contains`.

The error disappears if I declare TMyList = `class(TList<TMyEntry>)`;

Should I avoid `TObjectList<T>` or is something else in my code causing this error?

```
type
  TMyEntry = class(TStringlist);
  TMyList = class(TObjectList<TMyEntry>);

procedure TListTests.TestAV;
var
  Entry: TMyEntry;
  MyList: TMyList;
begin
  MyList := TMyList.Create;
  try
    Entry := TMyEntry.Create;

    MyList.Add(Entry);

    Assert(MyList.Contains(Entry));  // <--- AV

  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216733/generic-tlist-in-delphi-2009-crash-on-indexof

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde I wouldn't just say related, I'd say it's the exact same thing. `TObjectList<>` derives from `TList<>`, so bugs in `TList<>` show up in `TObjectList<>` too.

Answer (score 5):

This is the fix, based on the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216915/80901):

change

```
MyList := TMyList.Create;
```

to

```
MyList := TMyList.Create(TComparer<TMyEntry>.Default);
```

Comment: Color me surprised that the compiler doesn't just do the right thing here in 2009. This is fixed in XE and XE2 by the way. Why don't you just upgrade?